# How to avoid decoding to str: need a bytes-like object error in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, gensim, topic-modeling

Here is my code :

```
data = pd.read_csv('asscsv2.csv', encoding = "ISO-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False);
data_text = data[['content']]
data_text['index'] = data_text.index
documents = data_text
```

It looks like

```
print(documents[:2])
                                              content  index
 0  Pretty extensive background in Egyptology and ...      0
 1  Have you guys checked the back end of the Sphi...      1
```

And I define a preprocess function by using gensim

```
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
def lemmatize_stemming(text):
    return stemmer.stem(WordNetLemmatizer().lemmatize(text, pos='v'))
def preprocess(text):
    result = []
    for token in gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(text):
        if token not in gensim.parsing.preprocessing.STOPWORDS and len(token) > 3:
            result.append(lemmatize_stemming(token))
    return result
```

And when I use this function:

```
processed_docs = documents['content'].map(preprocess)
```

It appears

```
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, float found
```

How to encode my csv file to byte-like object or how to avoid this kind of error?

Comment: can you share full traceback?

Comment: Try using `documents['content'].astype(str).map(preprocess)`

Answer (score 11):

Your data has `NaNs`(not a number).

You can either drop them first:

```
documents = documents.dropna(subset=['content'])
```

Or, you can fill all `NaNs` with an empty string, convert the column to string type and then map your string based function.

```
documents['content'].fillna('').astype(str).map(preprocess)
```

This is because your function preprocess has function calls that accept string only data type.

**Edit:**

How do I know that your data contains NaNs?
Numpy nan are considered float values

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> type(np.nan)
<class 'float'>
```

Hence, you get the error

```
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, float found
```

Answer (score -1):

This :

```
processed_docs = documents['content'].map(preprocess)
```

is because the data frame in some cells has **NaN** **values** that can not be preprocessed, for that, you have to drop:

```
documents.dropna(subset = ["content"], inplace=True) # drop those rows which have NaN value cells
```

those unrequired rows and then apply the preprocessing.

this will solve your problem.